# Connecting two separate user systems on two different apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, discourse

I created two separate rails apps using two different user systems. One of them uses Devise and the other uses Discourse. What would be the best way to connect user data/info?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'connect'? Merge the apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an api to talk back and forth between the two apps.  Make sure if you do this that the communications is secured.